# Wordpress /wp-content change to /core, Giving error in fonts

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages

I recently installed **Hide My WP Ghost**; it changes my /wp-content/ change to /core. I remove the plunging but /wp-content/ is still /core/. How to fix it?

Now it's giving me font loading error and make slow my site.

```
GET https://eosty.com/core/fonts/poppins/pxiEyp8kv8JHgFVrJJfecg.woff2 net::ERR_ABORTED 404
GET https://eosty.com/core/fonts/poppins/pxiByp8kv8JHgFVrLGT9Z1xlFQ.woff2 net::ERR_ABORTED 404
```

I can't find way to back this changes.

Here is my error URL: https://eosty.com/top-5-moroccan-mythology-folklore-myths-and-legends/

Comment: You appear to have a cache, have you tried flushing it? Do you have a backup you can restore to?

Comment: Yes I clear all cache. And I've backup but it's very old with no blog post.

Answer (score 0):

Two possible solutions:

- Use a plugin like Better Search Replace to search for the string '/core/' and replace it with '/wp-content/' in your database.
- Restore your site from a recent backup

Comment: Better Search Replace I try this, But no results found